# How to add a default timeout to each retry?

Tags: python-requests

https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1393

I'm a bit confused after reading the above post.

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
data = s.get(MY_URL, timeout=10)
```

My understanding is that in 10 seconds, if there is no return value, there will be a timeout, and there will be no retries. What I want is for it to retry 3 times, and each try has a timeout of 10 seconds. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my understanding was wrong. If the number of retries is 3, and the timeout is 10, it will try 10 seconds for each of the 3 retries.

https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests
"Works In Conjunction With timeout" provides a good example, I just didn't understand it before.